After Chrome third-party cookie deprecation, can i implement one TAP Login in my AMP pages with consideration with FedCM
Can I implement one TAP Login in my AMP pages with consideration with FedCM. If yes then I want full integration doc and method to implement One tap login in my amp page with FedCM intregation.
Display One Tap in AMP pages is deprecated now, as per google recommendation developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/amp/amp. Is there any way to showcase One Tap login in AMP pages ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Display One Tap in AMP pages is deprecated now, as per google recommendation https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/amp/amp. Is there any way to showcase One Tap login in AMP pages ?
